# Parse XML files that has large number of nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a XML feed with the following URL with IDs of trips to be retrieved.

http://www.expeditiontrips.com/xml/triplist.xml

Based on the each trip information can be retrieved from following URL where the ID becomes the XML name

http://www.expeditiontrips.com/xml/trips/3481.xml

Now if u look at http://www.expeditiontrips.com/xml/trips/3481.xml link you can see there is an addition under additions node which has a label called "JRO Teaser". What i need to do is to parse these two files and show the list of trips that has this "JRO Teaser" label. The trips that includes this addition are discounted trips. I have written a code and it works with retrieving the list but the problem is since there are 518 nodes in first XML file it is taking like 5 mins to load the page. In other words its taking too much time to display result due to the large no. of trips. Can someone provide me a way to show this correctly without too much load time. Below is my code up to now.

```
    <?php 
        $ch = curl_init('http://www.expeditiontrips.com/xml/triplist.xml');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $xml_raw = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $trips = simplexml_load_string($xml_raw);

        $total = count($trips);

        for($a=0; $a<=$total; ++$a) { 

            $ch = curl_init('http://www.expeditiontrips.com/xml/trips/' . $trips->trip[$a] . '.xml');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $xml_raw = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            $info = simplexml_load_string($xml_raw);

            //print_r($info);

            $name = 'JRO Teaser';

            $tripss = $info->xpath("/trip/additions/addition/label");

            if($tripss[1] == 'JRO Teaser') {

                echo $info->code; 

            } 

        }       
    ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php - maybe faster

Comment: is there any way i can parse only items that has JRO Teaser label instead parsing all values and showing only the value that has it

Comment: load to simplexml and xpath use a lot of time. xmlreader reads tag by tag. You can find needed fragment by it. and do some processing  or even load this fragment to simplexml if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you can solve this by throwing machine power onto it - or just by asking for the right document to parse.

JRO most likely stands for *Just Released Offers*. You can gain a list of those by loading a HTML document into **DOMDocument** and use a bit of xpath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$saved = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($buffer);
libxml_use_internal_errors($saved);
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$ids = $xpath->query('//section/article[@class="sr search_result"]//input[@class="tc"]/@value');
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    echo $id->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

So instead of querying all documents your own, query that one website that does the querying for you already.

Still the rules to cache apply here. which already helps in developing such scrapers as you do.

```
$url = 'http://www.expeditiontrips.com/jro-list/?region=all&pricerange=special';
$key = 'scratch_3_' . md5($url);
if (file_exists($key)) {
    $buffer = file_get_contents($key);
} else {
    $buffer = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($key, $buffer);
}
```

Output:

```
3770
3025
3667
3781
3571
3078
3431
3433
3382
3173
3944
3887
3890
3731
2779
3313
3901
3900
3896
3430
3882
3884
2991
3777
3181
3921
3869
3935
3873
3923
3788
3789
3785
3786
3864
3927
3926
3054
3792
3793
3528
3928
3929
3930
3780
3790
3922
3810
3291
3796
3231
3835
2901
2883
3918
3815
3807
3808
3809
3919
3269
3734
3735
3718
3736
3904
3916
3917
3806
2548
3530
3760
2093
2704
3444
3489
3773
3772
2841
2842
3797
3932
2889
3891
3894
3895
3481
3938
3521
2547
3547
3589
3872
3939
3940
3620
3879
3545
3259
3933
2487
1831
3616
3188
3546
3838
3881
3749
3751
3131
3549
2806
3795
3062
3061
3931
3837
3142
1234
3799
2758
2490
3653
3068
3155
1929
2293
2975
2193
2923
3418
3122
2395
2846
2831
3119
3120
3802
2821
2820
3803
3801
3725
1555
3365
3228
3229
3204
3742
2410
3722
3412
3413
3174
3707
3434
3175
3383
3758
3631
3634
3679
3937
3870
3581
3897
3934
3778
3779
3924
3447
3583
3782
3768
3866
3548
3544
3821
3822
3925
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to process 500+ xml documents that average 18-25KB in size.
For me this takes 0.5-1 sec per document.

If your business logic permits, I suggest you do this outside your page load, for example in a cron job, every 30 minutes or 1 hour, and save the results in a database or even a text file on the server.

You could do it at higher frequencies depending on what you are after, ex. skip already processed id's or something on a similar note.

On the actual page load, just query your storage, flat file or database.

Changed your code around a little bit:

```
$trips = simplexml_load_file('http://www.expeditiontrips.com/xml/triplist.xml');

foreach ($trips as $tripId) {

    $info = simplexml_load_file('http://www.expeditiontrips.com/xml/trips/' . $tripId .'.xml');

    $name = 'JRO Teaser';

    foreach ($info->additions->addition as $add)
        if ($add->label==$name) $codes[] = (string)$info->code;

}

// process the $codes array, save to text file or database
// saveCodes($codes);
print_r($codes);
```